# Is it possible to get all of the artifacts without hacking or spending money?

Tags: tap-titans

On the Internet, it says the artifacts start costing tens of thousands of relics as you get more and more. At a gain of 1 relic per five levels and a few hundred per prestige (with the relic multiplying artifact), it doesn't seem possible to get all 30 relics without buying diamonds, hacking, or playing the game for a decade.

Is it possible to get all 30 relics without cheating or buying diamonds? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. It just takes a long time. But I'd say it's not worth to get every single relic.

[This artifact tier list is pretty helpfull.](https://www.reddit.com/r/TapTitans/comments/2vv2l9/artifact_tier_list/)

Your relic gain raises very very fast!

Answer (score 0):

It is ABSOLUTELY possible to do this without spending money. I have been playing for 2 months now and I have not bought any diamonds from the app store. The game is pretty generous when it comes to giving gems with video ads and fairy drops. The ONLY way this is possible without killing yourself is with the artifact Undead Aura. Without it, it is virtually impossible. I now get to stage 2300 or so and I make 50000 relics on average. It is VERY possible. Just level up Undead and you will be golden. Hope this helped.